# How to configure SimpleSAMLphp with Acquia platform?

Tags: apache, drupal-8, simplesamlphp, acquia

I'm following the instruction on Acquia's site https://docs.acquia.com/articles/using-simplesamlphp-acquia-cloud-site about configuring SimpleSAMLphp and it just seems the documentation is not very precise. In their documentation it says to run the following command to install SimpleSAMLphp library.

```
cd docroot; ln -s ../simplesamlphp/www simplesaml
```

And to install the **Install the simplesamlphp_auth Drupal module**, they linked to the **simpleSAMLphp Authentication** page, https://www.drupal.org/project/simplesamlphp_auth. And in the **SimpleSAMLphp Installation**, it's linked to the **SimpleSAMLphp Installation and Configuration** page, https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-install. However, the instruction in this page looks just like what I've done in the second step of Acquia's documentation. Instead of extract the simplesamlphp-1.x.y alongside the docroot, it suggest to extract it inside the var folder.

Now, once I've gone through the instruction on Acquia's documentation and tried to access the simplesaml, https://mywebsite.dd:8443/simplesaml/, I got the following error:

**Forbidden**
**You don't have permission to access /simplesaml/ on this server.**

So I found this thread, [Getting a 403 forbidden error for simplesaml after Apache upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337446/getting-a-403-forbidden-error-for-simplesaml-after-apache-upgrade/40120845), that talks about the error which looks like step 6 in the **SimpleSAMLphp Installation and Configuration** instruction. So I went to the /Applications/DevDesktop/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf and configured the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:8083>
     ServerAdmin userName@mywebsite.com
     DocumentRoot "/Users/userName/sites/drupalsites/docroot"
     ServerName drupalsites.local
     ServerAlias drupalsites.local
     ErrorLog "logs/drupalsites-error_log"
     CustomLog "logs/drupalsites-access_log" common
     <Directory "/Users/userName/sites/drupalsites/docroot">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </Directory>

     Alias /simplesaml simplesamlphp/www

    <Directory "/Users/userName/sites/drupalsites/simplesamlphp/www">
         Require all granted
     </Directory>

 </VirtualHost>
```

However, I'm still getting the same error.

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /simplesaml/ on this server.

So, the questions are, did I go about installing SimpleSAMLphp the wrong way? Second, if not, where did I go wrong? Third, how do I resolve this error and back on track again? I have also found this documentation, https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-to-configure-simplesamlphp-for-drupal-8-on-acquia, that talks about setting up SimpleSAMLphp on Aquia's plaform but it's not very consistent with other documentations I've listed above. So, I'm not sure which I should follow. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to your docroot/.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/simplesaml
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise with @realgt answer :

```
  # Copy and adapt this rule to directly execute PHP files in contributed or
  # custom modules or to run another PHP application in the same directory.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/core/modules/statistics/statistics.php$
+ # Allow access to simplesaml paths
+ RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/simplesaml
  # Deny access to any other PHP files that do not match the rules above.
  RewriteRule "^.+/.*\.php$" - [F]
```

This is provided in this link :
https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-to-configure-simplesamlphp-for-drupal-8-on-acquia